# Logic/Mathematics problems for training

Tags: logic, math-puzzle

Where I live, there is this competition called the "Känguru Wettbewerb" (german), in English, that would be "Kangaroo Competition". This is a mathematics competition where the goal is to solve problems that presuppose different areas of mathematics (like geometry, algebra etc.).

My question is, if there are any sources for problems like that, for training. I know the that problems of recent years are hosted on their website, but I'd like to know if there are any other sources that provide similar problems.

http://www.kaenguru.at/zum-herunterladen/aufgaben-der-vorjahre/2014/

On this site, there are the problems of 2014. Scroll down until you see the English version. The preferred level would be "Junior" in their system.

Are there any sources for problems like this? If yes, please post links.

Comment: One option would be to read the questions on Math.SE. I thought there was a 'competition maths' tag, but I can't see it currently.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure this will help but you could try UK maths challenges
http://www.ukmt.org.uk/individual-competitions/junior-challenge/